# Как вызвать метод внутри другого метода только  при 1 вызове

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Хочу чтобы при вызове метода первый раз вызывался другой(или условия),при другом вызове он уже не вызывался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
function firstTimeCalled()
{
    alert('call me one time');
}
function test()
{
    this.called = this.called || firstTimeCalled() || true;  
}
test();
test();
```

При первом вызове `test` будет вызвана функция `firstTimeCalled`.

Посмотреть можно здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/ApGfg/

Comment: Спасибо.Мне понравился очень способ

Comment: не за что)

Answer (score 3):

```
var Mtd = {

    open: function() {
        this.openFirst();

        alert(2);
    },

    openFirst: function() {
        alert(1);

        this.open = this.openFirst;
    }

}

var t = Mtd.open();
alert('next');
var r2 = Mtd.open();
```

Comment: Толково.Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Модно завести объект, а в нём метод и поле. Поле будет являться флагом, а при вызове метода, переключим флаг.

```
    MyObj = {
        var isRunner = false; // Установим в false, ведь не было ни одного запуска
        var fFunction = function(){
            // Первым делом проверим флаг
            if(isRunner){
                alert("Эта функция уже была вызвана");
                return;
            }else{
                // Переключаем флаг
                this.isRunner = true;
                // Твой код
            }

};

}
```

Ну и вызываем этот метод

```
MyObj.fFunction();
```

Comment: Кстати через флаг я и сделал.Сосед подсказал.Спасибо.